# Elastic Search - Maximum Shard Size

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, sharding

I came across and couldn't reach a final conclusion during learning ElasticSearch.

- What is the maximum shard size for ElasticSearch?
- How many shards can an index have? Is there any maximum limit?

Comment: Experts comments are based on complete/enough data which is missing in your case. Please add details like what is data, how it is spread, how you want to access etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading multiple articles and blogs and running my own load tests, I came to the conclusion that
number of shards and maximum size of each shard depends upon many factors like:

1. Size of the data inserted
2. Rate at which the data is inserted
3. Whether data retrieval / search is happening at the same time? If yes, what is the frequency of search? How many concurrent searches are done?
4. Server configuration details, like number of cores in CPU, hard disk size, Memory size etc

So, to find out the optimized size for each shard and optimized number of shards for a deployment, one good way is to run tests using various combinations of parameters & loads and arrive at a conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

- Simple : Don’t Cross 4 Billions documents
- Think about the limit of 32 bits systems of the Heap Size (still valid for 64 bits systems). ES recommand half memory up to 32 GB even for 64 bits systems, as it's concern memory handeling limit and optimization. If you have more than 64 GB of memory, you can keep further memory for Lucene?

For further details : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html and https://qbox.io/blog/optimizing-elasticsearch-how-many-shards-per-index .

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the theoretical maximum is very large, however depending on your system, there can be practical limits.

I've found that shards start to become less performant around 150GB. I've had 50GB shards that perform reasonably well. In both cases, the shard was the only shard on the node, and the node had 54GB of system memory, with 31GB devoted to elasticsearch. At 50GB, I was getting results from relatively heavy-duty queries around 100ms, and at 150GB it was taking 500ms or longer.

I'm sure this depends on the mappings I've used, and a host of other factors, but perhaps it's useful if you're polling for datapoints.